# split database table data into different array base on ID

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I have the following table

```
Vehicle_id   lat    long
A11         25.45   98.01
A11         26.45   98.02
B12         25.75   98.03
A11         25.25   98.04
B12         27.45   98.05
A11         25.35   98.06
C11         28.45   98.07
```

My codes:-

***controller code:***

```
public function get_location_data(){ 
    $data = $this->location_modal->get_location(); 
    $final = []; 
    /*foreach($data as $value){ 
        $final[$value['vehicle_id']] [] = $value; 
    }*/ 
    echo json_encode($data); 
}
```

***Modal code:***

```
function get_location() { 
    $this->db->select('*'); 
    $this->db->from('gps_data'); 
    $result = $this->db->get(); 
    return $result->result(); 
}
```

i want to get this data from table in different array based on vehicle_id and push all of them in json_encode. How do i accomplish this. Is it possible to construct a query that can do it or will i have to do it for individual vehicle_id store in array then add it to json encode. Please, help me get the solution.

Comment: `Select  *  from <table>` and then when your fetching records:- `$final = [];  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){$final[$row['Vehicle_id']][] = $row;} echo json_encode($final);`. That's it

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that i am using CodeIgniter. How to do it in codeigniter

Comment: Your solution is for custom php but i am using ci framework.

Comment: Please, check the code and help me.

Comment: please add what outocme you are getting with current code. do `var_dump($data);` after `$data = $this->location_modal->get_location(); ` and show what you are getting. Also add what you need as a final output also.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you loop over your table-rows:

```
$vehicles = [];
while($row = $db->fetch_assoc())
{
    $vehicles[$row['Vehicle_id']][]=$row;
}
```

You can ues  `Vehicle_id` as the array key for `$vehicles` and add the rows to it.

This will result in this json:

```
{
  "A11": [
    {
      "Vehicle_id": "A11",
      "lat": 25.45,
      "long": 98.01
    },
    {
      "Vehicle_id": "A11",
      "lat": 26.45,
      "long": 98.02
    },
    ...
  ],
  "B12": [
    {
      "Vehicle_id": "A11",
      "lat": 25.75,
      "long": 98.03
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

**Explaination:**

The syntax `$a[] = 1` appends `1` to the array `$a` resulting in:

```
[
    0=>1
]
```

This `$a['b'][] = 1` appends to the array at key `b` in array `$a` resulting in:

```
[
    'b'=>[0=>1]
]
```

Comment: I am doing it in Codeigniter, Please, do explain.

Comment: The assignment to the array works the same, Codeigniter or not.
In your current code the foreach is commented out, and the return value is $data. Can you comment the loop back in and change the return to $final? What is the json that is put out then?